# printf scanf Execution Order is getting exchanged

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
printf("Enter the value\n");
scanf("%d ",&data);
```

But `scanf` is getting executed before `printf`. What can be the reason?

This is my whole program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Queue{
    int front,rear;
    int capacity;
    int *array;
};

void enqueue(struct Queue *q){

    int data;
    if(q->front == (q->rear+1)%q->capacity){
        printf("Queue is full\n");
        return;
    }else{
        printf("Enter the value\n");
        scanf("%d ",&data);
        q->rear = (q->rear+1) % q->capacity;
        q->array[q->rear] =data;

        if(q->front == -1)
            q->front = q->rear;
    }

}
void dequeue(struct Queue *q){

    if( q->front == -1){
        printf("Queue is Empty\n");
        return;
    }else{
        printf("value dequeued %d \n",q->array[q->front]);
        if(q->front == q->rear)
            q->front = q->rear = -1;
        else
            q->front = (q->front+1)% q->capacity;
    }
}
void printQueue(struct Queue *q){

    if( q->front == -1){
        printf("Queue is Empty\n");
        return;
    }else{
        int f = q->front, r =q->rear;

        while((f% (q->capacity)) != r)
        {
            printf ("\t %d", q->array[f] );
            f++;
        }
    printf("\t %d",q->array[q->rear]);
    printf("\n");
    }
}


main(){

    struct Queue *q = malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
    if(!q){
        printf("Memory Error\n");
        exit;
    }
    q->capacity = 3;
    q->front= q->rear = -1;
    q->array = malloc(q->capacity * sizeof(int));   
    if(!q->array){
        printf("Memory Error\n");
        exit;
    }

    int option;
    char ch ='a';
    while(1) {
        printf("Enter the choice 1.Enqueue or 2.Dequeue 3.print\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d",&option);
        switch(option){
        case 1:
            enqueue(q);                 
            break;
        case 2:
            dequeue(q);
            break;
        case 3:
            printQueue(q);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong choice\n");
        }


    printf("Do you want to continue? press y to continue\n");
    scanf("%s", &ch);
    if(ch != 'y')break;
    }
}
```

When I enqueue an element it waits for the input and after that printf statement gets executed i. e Do you want to continue.
Ideally when I enter the element to enqueue and hit the enter it should ask me do you want to continue and then it should wait for the input ie 'y'. But as soon i enter the element for enqueue it waits for the input 'y' and after entering 'y' ,"do you want to continue" gets executed

Comment: No, it's not.[‍](http://www.google.com)

Comment: I am using ubuntu's default gcc compiler

Comment: Why makes you believe it's being reordered?

Comment: This is part of my code, I will post the entire code wait

Comment: The line `scanf("%s", &ch);` is not right. Did you mean `scanf("%c", &ch);`?

Comment: stdout is buffered by default.  Flush stdout after the printf, (before the scanf), and you'll see what you expect.  That answers your question.  But you have other issues in your code... which has been expounded upon below...  (see `setvbuf` (`man setvbuf`) to turn off stdout buffering if you wish)

Comment: `scanf("%s", &ch);` --> `scanf(" %c", &ch);`  Add space and s to c.  (`"%d "` --> `"%d"` as OP already noted)

Answer (score 0):

Reworked the question code.  The biggest problem was using scanf(), which leaves unread values (such as carriage returns) behind in stdin.  The unread characters interfere with the next use of scanf().  Changed the scanf() to gobble up the superfluous characters from stdin by adding `%*c` to the format strings:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Queue{
    int front,rear;
    int capacity;
    int *array;
};

void enqueue(struct Queue *q){

    int data;
    if(q->front == (q->rear+1)%q->capacity){
        printf("Queue is full\n");
        return;
    }else{
        printf("Enter the value\n");
        scanf(" %d%*c",&data);
        q->rear = (q->rear+1) % q->capacity;
        q->array[q->rear] =data;

        if(q->front == -1)
            q->front = q->rear;
    }

}
void dequeue(struct Queue *q){

    if( q->front == -1){
        printf("Queue is Empty\n");
        return;
    }else{
        printf("value dequeued %d \n",q->array[q->front]);
        if(q->front == q->rear)
            q->front = q->rear = -1;
        else
            q->front = (q->front+1)% q->capacity;
    }
}
void printQueue(struct Queue *q){

    if( q->front == -1){
        printf("Queue is Empty\n");
        return;
    }else{
        int f = q->front, r =q->rear;

        while((f% (q->capacity)) != r)
        {
            printf ("\t %d", q->array[f] );
            f++;
        }
    printf("\t %d",q->array[q->rear]);
    printf("\n");
    }
}


int main()
   {
   int  option;
   char ch ='a';

   struct Queue *q = malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
   if(!q)
      {
      printf("Memory Error\n");
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   q->capacity = 3;
   q->front= q->rear = -1;
   q->array = malloc(q->capacity * sizeof(int));
   if(!q->array)
      {
      printf("Memory Error\n");
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   while(1)
      {
      printf("Enter the choice 1.Enqueue or 2.Dequeue 3.print\n");
      scanf(" %d%*c",&option);
      switch(option)
         {
         case 1:
            enqueue(q);
            break;

         case 2:
            dequeue(q);
            break;

         case 3:
            printQueue(q);
            break;

         default:
            printf("Wrong choice\n");
            break;
         }


   printf("Do you want to continue? press y to continue\n");
   scanf(" %c%*c", &ch);
   if(ch != 'y')
      break;
   }

CLEANUP:

   return(0);
   }
```

Comment: Thank u very much .actually the code worked fine when I removed the space after %d

Comment: I changed scanf("%d ",&data)to("%d",&data)